# Are the View Model equals to the View in UML?

Tags: oop, architecture, uml, modeling, system-analysis

I am studying UML OOA and OOD.  There are two concepts `View Model` and `View` in "Kruchten 4+1 view model":

[image]

[image]

The terms are not all identical.  Do these two picture mean the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In short

Yes, these two view models are the same. It's a slight terminological evolution made by Krutchen himself: the former *development view* is now the *implementation view*, and the *physical view* became the *deployment view*.

While this terminology was influenced by UML, **UML does not use these views at all**.

### More details

The [***view model***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_model) is a general term that refers to the use of different views to analyse or design a same system under different angles:

- Krutchen's ***4+1 view model*** is independent of UML.  In his [first article on 4+1 in 1995](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1109/52.469759), he referred to the *logical*, *process*, *physical*, *development* and *scenario/use-case* views.  This corresponds to your first diagram.
- However, Krutchen worked closely together with the founders of UML at Rational, and he published [another article in 1996](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/243327.243334) on software architecture where he described his 4+1 view model with a slightly different terminology: *logical*, *process*, *implementation*, *deployment* and *use-cas*e views.  This correspond to your second diagram.

UML specifications do not refer to 4+1 views at all. UML's view model is based on semantic areas that are reflected in the diagram types.  On Wikipedia, you'll find an article on [4+1 architectural view model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4%2B1_architectural_view_model) with a mapping from the view with their old terminology, to UML diagram types, but this is not authoritative and Krutchen's article uses a different one.